# How to recover files from windows backup tool with Invalid MediaID.bin?

Tags: file-recovery, windows-7-backup, join

I have a backup from 2009 with the extension **.wbcat** and after I opened windows 7 backup and recovery tool and selected the folder that contained this backup, there was the error: **"Invalid MediaID.bin"**

I tried to extract all the files with winrar using Extract here in hope that it would join split files. However, there were several errors and I discovered that the errors were from the split files.

However, it's not possible to join them using winrar, or at least, I don't know how.
I put a note with every number of part that had an error:

145
146
147
149
151
152
155
156
158
160
163
164
167
168
172
175
176
180
186
187
191
192
194
199
200
203
204
209
214
217
218
221
222
228

***How can I join these files?*** They have all the same name. Example:
one of the parts has

part03.zip : file1.avi (200MB); file1.avi (10KB)
part04.zip : file1.avi (200MB); file1.avi (30KB)

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved the problem:

Opened an excel and looked at every part number near the ones with error, despite not having an error.

Example:
if **part03 has error**, then lets see what is there on part02 and part01. *It turns out, they can have parts of the file.*

Therefore, I did something like:

| partnumber | filename | folder1 | folder 2 | folder 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| part02 | example.AVI | videos | user | C |
| part03 | example.AVI | videos | user | C |
| part04 | example.AVI | videos | user | C |

Then, extract each folder and each file, they must be different. Winrar will try to substitute files like example.AVI (200 MB) and example.AVI (10KB), however, you must **make sure they are extracted and rename them** adding .0x to the extension and x being the number of the file.

After this process and extracting part02, 03 and 04 we can have something like:

example.AVI.01; example.AVI.02; example.AVI.03; example.AVI.04; example.AVI.05

Now lets join them using cmd.

Change the directory to your folder, example:

```
cd c:\test
```

And now lets join them using

```
copy /b example.AVI.01+example.AVI.02+example.AVI.03+example.AVI.04+example.AVI.05 example.AVI
```

Now we have our final file called **example.AVI**.

Comment: Also, if you're curious, these are the part numbers I had to figure out. They were always the number right before the one I had error, when there would be a new file: 144; 148; 150; 154; 157; 159; 162; 166; 171; 174; 179; 185; 190; 193; 198; 202; 208; 213; 216; 220; 227.